# How to make Yodlee Fastlink2.0 work only with banks

Tags: yodlee

I am trying to integrate Yodlee Fastlink2.0 to my website. I want user to be able to add only bank accounts, no other financial institutes are needed for my website. Is there any parameter I can add to the Fastlink2.0 Url to make it suggest only banks? I suspect that extraParams='keyword=bank' may work, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, please connect with Yodlee support team and ask them that you need only bank accounts. They will configure this for your environment. Once this is done, you don't have to worry about other accounts. User will add bank site normally and Fastlink 2.0 will return only bank accounts, even if user may have other type of accounts within the same bank.